# How to use slots in the HTML with Single File Components

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-cli

I want to use slots in Vue to create a dynamic modal component.

I already tried a lot of tutorials of Vue / slots, but none of them is exactly what i'm looking for.

This is a piece of my `modal.vue`:

```
<template>
  ...
    <slot name="modal-body"></slot>
  ...
</template>
<script>
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

This is my javascript compiled file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import modal from './modal.vue';

new Vue({
  el: '#modal',
  render: r => r(modal)
});
```

This is piece of my HTML file:

```
...
<div id="modal">
  <template v-slot="modal-body">
    <input type="text" id="dynamic-input">
  </template>
</div>
...
```

I was expecting that all elements present inside `#modal` (`#dynamic-input` in this case), were inserted into the slot named `modal-body`, inside my Vue element.
Is it possible to do it? Am i missing something?

Comment: Actually, what version of Vue are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.6.10

Comment: I tried with some other versions, but they also didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check what version of Vue you are using.  The [named slot syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Named-Slots) changed in 2.6.0.  Consider the differences below.  One uses render functions and the other template Strings.

### Vue@2.6.10

```js
// Example using template String
const modalTemplateString = {
  template: "<div><div>above</div><slot name=\"modal-body\"></slot><div>below</div></div>"
};

const appTemplateString = new Vue({
  el: "#appTemplateString",
  components: {
    modal: modalTemplateString
  },
  template: "<div><modal><template v-slot:modal-body><div>foobar</div></template></modal></div>"
});

// Example using render function
const modalRenderFunc = {
  render(h) {
    return h("div", [
      h("div", "above"),
      h("div", this.$slots["modal-body"]),
      h("div", "below")
    ]);
  }
}

const appRenderFunc = new Vue({
  el: "#appRenderFunc",
  components: {
    modal: modalRenderFunc
  },
  render(h) {
    return h("div", [
      h("modal", [
        h("div", {
          slot: "modal-body"
        }, "foobar")
      ])
    ]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>

<h2>Template String</h2>
<div id="appTemplateString"></div>
<hr/>
<h2>Render Function</h2>
<div id="appRenderFunc"></div>
```

### Vue@2.5.22

```js
// Example using template String
const modalTemplateString = {
  template: "<div><div>above</div><slot name=\"modal-body\"></slot><div>below</div></div>"
};

const appTemplateString = new Vue({
  el: "#appTemplateString",
  components: {
    modal: modalTemplateString
  },
  template: "<div><modal><template slot=\"modal-body\"><div>foobar</div></template></modal></div>"
});

// Example using render function
const modalRenderFunc = {
  render(h) {
    return h("div", [
      h("div", "above"),
      h("div", this.$slots["modal-body"]),
      h("div", "below")
    ]);
  }
}

const appRenderFunc = new Vue({
  el: "#appRenderFunc",
  components: {
    modal: modalRenderFunc
  },
  render(h) {
    return h("div", [
      h("modal", [
        h("div", {
          slot: "modal-body"
        }, "foobar")
      ])
    ]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.22/dist/vue.js"></script>

<h2>Template String</h2>
<div id="appTemplateString"></div>
<hr/>
<h2>Render Function</h2>
<div id="appRenderFunc"></div>
```

Comment: Nice! But this is only half of what i wan to do. Consider instead of writing just a string  ("foobar" in your exemple), i have an entire form to insert in the modal body. Additionally, the form won't be inside the javascript file, but in the HTML.

I want to know if, somehow, it's possible to grab all elements inside "<div id="modal">" and put them into the slot, this piece is essential.

Comment: And i tested your exemple in my environment, and the HTML is not parsed, it's just text =/

Comment: Anyone? I used another approach but this solution could be useful sometimes.

Comment: People? Anyone to help here? =/

Comment: Feel free to help if you can =)

Comment: Just want to know if it's possible to do it or not.

Comment: Btw, i want to use it with blades in Laravel.